# Headers not re-directing (and there aren't any errors)

Tags: php, redirect, header

This is a very strange issue. In my code I have a redirect that works perfectly on my local server.

```
header("location:/sign-up-success");
```

When I push to production, it just doesn't redirect. Is there a setting that I am missing?

I have even tried:

```
header("Location: https://www.myurl.com/sign-up-success");
```

It appears to just skip over the redirect. Any ideas?

Comment: Check your error log for any PHP warnings/errors? Your production server might not report them directly to the browser.

Comment: A header redirect should `exit` after redirecting, thus "it should [not] skip over the redirect" but just die instead (if done right). Also, you may have `output_buffering` enabled on your local server but not in production. Try turning it off on your local machine (as well as enabling errors like @Amber suggested).

Comment: @Amber - There weren't any errors in the error log. That is the weird thing.

Comment: @netcoder - output_buffering was off on my production server. I went ahead and turned it on and that fixed it! THANK YOU! (In particular to those who have a similar problem, in the php.ini file on my local machine I had "output_buffering = 4096" and on the production server it was set at "output_buffering = off". Turning it on fixed it and some other problems as well.

Comment: @Jason, you could post this as an answer youself and select it as the correct solution .

Comment: Take a look to this warning: 
Note: HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as argument to » Location: including the scheme, hostname and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs. You can usually use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and dirname() to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself. http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: @Jason: Perhaps your error reporting level on your production server was set too low for the "headers already sent" warning to be logged.

Comment: @no.good.at.coding - stackoverflow wouldn't let me post the answer until 8 hrs later. I just posted it but it won't let me confirm it as the answer for another 24hrs. I will do so once I am able.

Comment: @Jason, I would advise you to solve the problem rather than to blindly turn on output buffering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all the responses. It appears the answer to this question was given by @netcoder in the comments. The answer is found below:

In the php.ini file on my local machine I had "output_buffering = 4096" and on the production server it was set at "output_buffering = off". Turning it on fixed the header issue and some other problems as well.

For those with other headers problems, please review the other responses as they will be helpful if you have error reporting turned off. (I had run into that before, that's why I knew that wasn't the problem but that can certainly be a headache for people working with redirects and not knowing what the problem is).

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

**possible reason:** you have sent some output to the browser before the call of `header()`
**solution  :** write `ob_start()` at the top of the page

*Best practice* : alwyas write `exit()` after `header()`..

**[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)**

Comment: Adding `ob_start()` is a workaround rather than solution. Solution would be to eliminate any output.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at value of `error_reporting` on production server. If it is set to too low level, there will be nothing in the log, as errors of lower level than `error_reporting` are just silently ignored. Same applies to using `@` - it sets `error_reporting` to 0, so if anything bad happens (e.g., if function is not even defined), you won't see anything in the log.

From what you wrote about enabling output buffering, it seems that you have some output before `header()` (this is why enabling output buffering helps) and that your `error_reporting` is set to 0 (this is why warning about "Cannot modify header information" was not being reported/logged).

---

On a side note... To get the most of error reporting:

- set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL | E_STRICT` (in both dev and production environments)
- enable error logging (critical for production environment, though it won't hurt to have it enabled in dev environment as well)
- set `display_error` to `true` in dev environment, `false` in production environment (critical!!! user does not have to see any PHP warnings/notices/errors)
- additionally, you might want to [`set_error_handler()`](http://www.php.net/set_error_handler) to output or log more information than default error handler does (e.g., you might want to store [`debug_backtrace()`](http://www.php.net/debug_backtrace), when error occurs)

Answer (score 0):

> It appears to just skip over the redirect.

You need to have a look at exactly what the script is returning in headers / content. There are lots of tools available for this - HTTP fiddler, iehttpheaders for MSIE, for Firefox there's tamperdata, liveheaders, web developer toolbar and many more. Or sniff the network traffic (though decoding ssl can be a PITA)